Why is my recursive function not returning all of the data?
I have a python function to return all the files in some directory (and its sub-directories) as a numpy array, it goes over all of the files (as shown by the print statement), but only returns the ones in the file path specified, whats happening? Heres my minimal reproducible version:
import os
import numpy as np

def read_path(path, items):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if "." in item:
            items = np.append(items, f"{path}\{item}")
            print(f"File: {item}")
        else:
            read_path(f"{path}\{item}", items)
            print(f"Folder: {item}")
    return items

f = np.array([])
print(
    read_path(r"D:\Reubens stuff\Code Stuff\code saves\Python\Create Texture Pack\samples-load\resource_pack\textures", f)
)


Typo?  The else block never modifies items.  (That is, the return value of read_path is ignored in the else block.)

This question is similar to: Why does my recursive function return None?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should look at pathlib.Path.rglob and not reinvent the wheel, e.g., files = np.array([file for file in pathlib.Path('<your_path>').rglob('*') if file.is_file()])

As pointed out by David, you need to add the return value of the recursion to the original items array.
Hence, the following code should work:
import os
import numpy as np

def read_path(path, items):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        full_path = os.path.join(directory_path, item)
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            items = np.append(items, f"{path}\{item}")
            print(f"File: {item}")
        else:
            items = np.append(items, read_path(f"{path}\{item}", items))
            print(f"Folder: {item}")
    return items

f = np.array([])
print(
    read_path(r"D:\Reubens stuff\Code Stuff\code saves\Python\Create Texture Pack\samples-load\resource_pack\textures", f)
)


Recursion is based on the combining of returned results. But your return statement is useless. You'd better use either the global variable f or a classical recursion:
import os

def read_path(path):
    items=[]
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if "." in item:
            items.append(f"{path}/{item}")
            print(f"File: {item}")
        else:
            items.append(read_path(f"{path}/{item}"))
            print(f"Folder: {item}")
    return items

print(
    read_path(r"D:\Reubens stuff\Code Stuff\code saves\Python\Create Texture Pack\samples-load\resource_pack\textures"")
)

I also suggest to determine whether item is a file or a directory by this condition:
os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, item))


The root cause of your issue is that numpy.append isn't like list.append. It does not modify the array (or list) in place. Rather, it returns an array containing a copy of data in the input container (plus the item to be appended). This means that after the first recursion, you're operating on a different items object than the one that was initially passed in.
If you want the new value to be passed back out, you need to do items = read_path(f"{path}\{item}", items) in the else block, so that items gets updated in every case.
